# underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent' is not working for native-base Input field?

Tags: react-native, native-base

underlineColorAndroid prop is not working. Grey underline is still present for an Input field

```
<Item style='name_input_container'>
  <Input style={styles.name_input}
  autoCorrect={false} 
  placeholder='Enter name'
  selectionColor='#ffa500'
  textAlign={'center'}
  underlineColorAndroid: 'transparent'
  />
</Item>
```

Comment: I have also run code with underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

Comment: are you using the native base or react native input component

Comment: @Zeeshan Ansari I am using native base

Answer (score 1):

Change `underlineColorAndroid: 'transparent'` to `underlineColorAndroid='transparent'` so the final output will be like:

```
<Item style='name_input_container'>
  <Input style={styles.name_input}
  autoCorrect={false} 
  placeholder='Enter name'
  selectionColor='#ffa500'
  textAlign={'center'}
  underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
  />
</Item>
```

Comment: what do you mean by snake? is it snake case i.e underline_color_android?